# How to bind previous date when minDate is set "datetimepicker"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

It's sample code.
It is ok when date comes from database is greater than today date. But when date is less than today, datetimepicker doesn't display, only blank.
I tried to bind using "date:" option. It doesn't work.

How can I bind date from sever when `minDate` is set in javascript?

```
$('.date-noclear').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
    showClose: true,
    toolbarPlacement: 'top',
    showTodayButton: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Min date in datetimepicker is set so that, user wont be able to select dates prior to this minDate. So you can set any date after this minDate in datetimepicker, but not a date less than this.

Comment: yeah but I need to display date from sever at first. When users want to set new date, i need to let them only date greater than today.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by binding values manually into datetime textbox.

```
var replace = '/';
            var pDate = "@Model.PublishedDate".split('-').join(replace);
            var dDate = "@Model.DueDate".split('-').join(replace);

            $('#PublishedDate').val(pDate);
            $('#DueDate').val(dDate);
```

Now it's ok.